# Column 'Fecha' does not belong to table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datetime, html-table

The data type of 'fecha' on sql server is datetime. How can I show this data type datetime to this table below.

```
 <tbody>
            <% for (var data = 0; data < TableData.Rows.Count; data++)
               { %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Contraloría General de la República Dominicana
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%=TableData.Rows[data]["NOMBRE"]%>  
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%=TableData.Rows[data]["PUESTO"]%>  
                </td>                
                <td>
                    <%=TableData.Rows[data]["ESTADO"]%>  
                </td>     

                <td>
                    <%=TableData.Rows[data]["Fecha"]%> 
                </td>              

                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <%if (TableData.Rows[data][3].ToString() == "True")
                      { %>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="chcktbl1" checked="checked" name="chcktbl1" data-id="<%=TableData.Rows[data]["ID"]%>" />
                    <%} %>
                    <%else
                      { %>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="chcktbl1" name="chcktbl1" id="checkbox" data-id="<%=TableData.Rows[data]["ID"]%>" />
                    <%} %>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <% } %>
        </tbody>
```

How to add the data type datetime in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure for case in your array index  (accessing sql by the index is case sensitive)

```
  <td>
      <%=TableData.Rows[data]["FECHA"]%> 
  </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<td>
    <%=TableData.Rows[data]["FECHA"].ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")%> 
</td>
```

Regards.